# Виртуальный конструктор, С++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class vera;
class vasa;

class artem {
 public:
    artem(): art(NULL) {
    } artem(istream & io) {
        string s;
        io >> s;
        switch (constr(s)) {
        case VERA:
            art = new vera(s);
            break;
        case VASA:
            art = new vasa(s);
            break;
        }
    }
    virtual ~artem()
    {delete art;}
    virtual void show() {
        art->show();
    }
    virtual void set(string ch) {
        art->set(ch);
    }
 private:
    artem * art;
    enum ludi { VERA, VASA };
    ludi constr(string ss) {
        if (ss == "VERA")
            return VERA;
        else if (ss == "VASA")
            return VASA;
        else
            cout << "Takogo net" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
};

class vera:public artem {
    string name;
 public:
     vera(): artem(){}
     vera(string cc): artem(), name(cc){}
     void show() {
        cout << name << endl;
    }
    void set(string ch) {
        name = ch;
    }
};

class vasa:public artem {
    string name;
 public:
    vasa(): artem(){}
vasa(string cc): artem(), name(cc){} 
    void show() {
        cout << name << endl;
    }
    void set(string ch) {
        name = ch;
    }
};
```

Вот решил поупражнятся по памяти над темой "виртуальных конструкторов", но что-то не так, имеется вышеуказанный код, но выдается ошибка vera: не имеет конструкторов vasa не имеет конструкторов, подскажите, чего я тут напортачил. Спасибо.

кому интересно, вот результат проб и ошибок:)
проблема оказалась в том, что опереждающее обьявление почемуто(нужно еще осмыслить) не давало требуемого результата, решилось все путем определения конструктора базового класса после всех производных, когда они уже видны.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class artem
    {
    public:
        artem(): art(NULL){}
        artem(istream & io);
        virtual ~artem()
            {
            delete art;
            }
        virtual void show()
            {
            art->show();
            }
        virtual void set(istream &io)
            {
            art->set(io);
            }
        virtual void du(int a, int b)
            {
            art->du(a, b);
            }
    private:
        enum ludi{VERA, VASA};  
        ludi constr(string ss)
            {
            if(ss=="VERA")
                return VERA;
            else
                if(ss=="VASA")
                    return VASA;
                else
                    cout<<"Takogo net"<<endl;
                    exit(0);
            }
        artem *art;
    };

class vera: public artem
    {
    friend artem;
    string name;
    vera(string cc): name(cc){}
    public:
        void show()
            {
            cout<<name<<endl;
            }
        void set(istream &io)
            {
                string s;
                io>>s;
                name=s;
            }
        void du(int a, int b)
            {
            cout<<a+b<<endl;
            }
    };

class vasa: public artem
    {
    friend artem;
    string name;
    vasa(string cc): name(cc){}
    public:
        void show()
            {
            cout<<name<<endl;
            }
        void set(istream &io)
            {
                string s;
                io>>s;
                name=s;
            }
        void du(int a, int b)
            {
            cout<<a*b<<endl;
            }
    };

artem::artem(istream &io)
            {
            string s;
            io>>s;
            switch(constr(s))
                {
            case VERA:
                art=new vera(s);
                break;
            case VASA:
                art=new vasa(s);
                break;
                }
            }
```

Теперь вот думаю взятся за прототипы, только вот ни как не соберусь.
Спасибо всем за участие. Удачи.

Comment: @ttiimm Отредактируйте, пожалуйста, свой код. Это способствует более быстрому и правильному ответу.

Answer (score 2):

Классы наследники не имеют конструкторов без параметров, в то время как их базовый класс имеет только один конструктор (без параметров). Определив свой конструктор, вы обязаны вызвать базовый конструктор вручную (некоторые компиляторы это делают, а некоторые нет). На заметку, если у вас есть динамическая память, а она у вас есть, то необходимо объявить деструктор, в котором вы будете ее освобождать. Если вы планируете отнаследоваться от данного класса, то деструктор должен быть виртуальным.

Comment: Как я понял, мой компилятор не хочет сам вызывать конструктор без параметров базового класса, даже если и так, то вызов его вручную проблему не решил. Хотя может я не так понял Ваш совет, уже даже начал пробовать вариации на тему добавления в производные классы конструкторов без параметров  и вызов из них базового также не принесли результат. По поводу виртуального деструктора - просто забыл:) отвлекся с этими конструкторами. спасибо

Comment: Обновите, плиз, код, чтоб понять, что не так.

Comment: после изменения строк
vera(string cc): name(cc){} 
на vera(string cc): artem(), name(cc){}
и
vasa(string cc): name(cc){} 
на vasa(string cc): artem(), name(cc){}
а так же добавления 
vera(): artem(){}
и
vasa(): artem(){}
изменений нет, подозреваю я не так понял совет.